# how do i have to wrap codepush component on react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

is it okay if I use codepush like this?

in my index.js

```
const RNRedux = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => RNRedux);
```

I wrapped app component with redux provider

and in my App component has a lot of react-navigations.

```
App.js component looks like
```

```
  </NavigationContainer>

      <Stack.Screen

      />
      <Stack.Screen

      />
      <Stack.Screen

      />
      <Stack.Screen

      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
```

export default CodePush(codePushOptions)(App);

```
I'm curious if I use codepush like this? I've heard that codepush has to be wrapped top of the components 

do I have to replace index.js and app.js ?




thanks for reading my question!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to import in an index.js file, below is the updated code of your index.js file.

**Index.js**

```
 const RNRedux = () => (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
       <CodePush />
      </Provider>
    );
    
    AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => RNRedux);
```

**App.js**

```
  <Stack.Screen

  />
  <Stack.Screen

  />
  <Stack.Screen

  />
  <Stack.Screen

  />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: import in the index.js and wrap app.js components?

Comment: @questionsmas i have edited my answer you can implement like this.

Comment: I've done without CodePush(codePushOptions)(App) in App.js but it didn't work

Comment: you can refer this for better understanding : - https://medium.com/cybermonkey/mastering-over-the-air-updates-in-react-native-with-codepush-part-1-faf241a7f84b

Comment: AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () =>
  CodePush(codePushOptions)(RNRedux),
); I think it works thanks